# Make Nginx download PHP files instead of executing

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I'm making a website where my friends and I want to be able to send files to each other, and those files might be of any extension, the problem is that if they send a PHP file, it won't download the file, but instead execute it.

What I want to know is if there is any way to make Nginx serve the file directly instead of executing it, if it's in a specific directory. Preferably a .htaccess, but its hosted on a VPS so I can do config files and similar aswell.

Comment: Separate question, why not use one of the many many existing apps that will let you do that?

Comment: I second @JonStirling: take a look at the `nextcloud` solution: it offers what you want and a ton more of useful things especially for a group of people looking for a collaboration solution.

Comment: It's just something I want to code for fun, that's why I don't use a 3rd party solution.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's nginx issue. Try adding additional extension on the file, e.g. `index.php.up`. automatically add that when uploading and before hitting the server (use JavaScript). And before showing at the other end remove additional extension `.up`